# how to check letter by letter in a word and make change accordignly?? html js... typing game

Tags: javascript, html, game-development

typing game.... im working on this menu for my game.. and i have this problem:

i have 2 words on the screen and a typing zone where it checks for keys and display it on screen...

i want for every correct letter in the typing zone if it matches the letters of one of the words ... the letter would turn "green" else "red".... sorry for my bad english

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Madimi+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Typo game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label id="playerInput">start</label>
    <label id="options">options</label>
    <label id="TypeZone">sssssss</label>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
*{
  font-family: "Madimi One", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}
#playerInput{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 45%;
  transform: translate(-50% -50%);
  font-size: 3em;
  color: aliceblue;
}
#options{
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 43%;
  transform: translate(-50% -50%);
  font-size: 3em;
  color: aliceblue;
}
#TypeZone{
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 67%;
  transform: translate(-50% -50%);
  font-size: 3em;
  color: aliceblue;
}
```

```
const start= document.querySelector("#playerInput");
const get_start = [...start.textContent]

const options = document.querySelector("#options");
const get_options = [...options.textContent]

let inputX = "";
let getInputX = true;



const type = document.querySelector("#TypeZone")



// get input from keyboard and display on screen
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  
    if (getInputX) {
      inputX += event.key;
      type.textContent = inputX;

      
      if (inputX.length >= get_options.length) {
          getInputX = false;
      }
    }
    if (get_start.includes(event.key)){
      start.style.color ="green"; /// what i want to do is to turn letter green for each correct letter and so on
    }
    else{
      start.style.color = "red";
    }
    if (get_options.includes(event.key)){
      options.style.color ="green"; /// 
    }
    else{
      options.style.color = "red";
    }

  // if typed start or options >> start the game
  if (inputX === "start" || inputX === "options"){
    window.location.href = "game.html";
  }
  
});
```

here s what i tried so far

Comment: You want to change `label` to `input`. And define the right word first. 

Comment: why use input??

Comment: Because where do you want to get the user `input` fromi?

Comment: @deEr. , the programmer can use the events such as `keydown` or `keypress`, and this is nicer if the whole game is just typing

Comment: @hasandarwish Ah, i see. But then the user has to see what he typed. Because otherwise it becomes a **Typo Game** .

Comment: @deEr. just see my answer, and the code, the user can see the outpyt from another text element, the input element is good, but not customizable, we want to change the color of the word, and maybe, each letter

Comment: @hasandarwish https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/9o13q0s2/2/ This is how I imagine it to be. 

Answer (score 0):

what do you actually need ?
if you need to check if the word is written right or wrong, check this out :

```js
const word = "hello world" // Define the word, anything should work
const tdElement = document.getElementById("TypeZone") // A shortcut for text display element
var typed = "" // The place where the input goes from user, and keypress event

onkeypress = function(key){
switch(key.key) { // Get the key pressed
case "Enter" :
// The code to deal with the enter press
break

case "Backspace" :
// Here, we will delete a character from the typed variable :
if(typed.length > 0) typed = typed.slice(0,typed.length-1)
break

// Any key else, just add it, I am too lazy to check for letters, do this for you if you want
default :
typed += key.key
break
}

// Finally check for correct letters
let userWords = new Array(...typed)
let words = new Array(...word)
tdElement.innerHTML = ""
words.forEach(function(w, index){
if(w == userWords[index]) tdElement.innerHTML += `<span style="color:lime;">${w}</span>`
else tdElement.innerHTML += `<span style="color:red;">${w}</span>`
})
}
```

tell me if this worked.

***EDIT*** if you want to make the full word to be at the same color, it is too easy, just replace the code after the last comment into

```js
if(word == typed) tdElement.style.color = "lime"
else tdElement.style.color = "red"
```

and to limit the word length, just make it on the keypress event (before word checking) :

```js
let maxLength = 15 // Put your number
typed = typed.slice(0, maxLength-1)
// Checking code
```

Comment: Nice. It is expected behaviour, that the whole word shows? https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/9o13q0s2/1/ .

Comment: @deEr. , sorry, but this code I wrote it from mobile, hope it worked, as I couldn't test it

Comment: @hasandarwish Congrats ,